# Not getting output when trying to get average of array

Tags: javascript

Code:

```
var Array = [];

leggtil.onclick = function leggtil() {

    const input = +document.getElementById('input').value;
    Array.push(input);
    console.log(Array);

}
function beregn(tabell) {

    var sum = tabell.reduce(add, 0);

    function add(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    const gjenn =  (sum/tabell.length);
    console.log(gjenn);
    return gjenn;
}

beregn.onclick = function display() {

    console.log(beregn(Array));

}
```

I know this could be condensed into one function, but i want to give a shot at using parameters. When i run display() however, nothing at all happens. Is there something i have misunderstood? (Also, please keep an eventual solution with the parameters intact, so i learn more about how they work!)

Comment: It looks like you tried to add an onclick event to a function. Not sure what you meant for that to do. `function beregn(tabell) {}` and then `beregn.onclick = ...` I think you should check the console for errors and start researching them 1 by 1.

Comment: Also strongly recommend **not** using `Array` as a variable name, especially not at global scope. It'll work, but only until code tries to use `Array` for its standard meaning (the constructor for arrays).

Comment: Array is reserved in js. Also the onclick function can be written like anarrow fn.

Comment: don't understand what's going up there. one thing is clear **beregn([1,2,3,4]);**
working like charms. :)

Comment: As @klvenky said, `Array` is a reserved term in Javascript. You cannot use that as a variable name (well, you can, but you really and definitely shouldn't). Aside from that your code shows why it is widely considered bad practice to use non-English names for variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
function beregn(tabell) {

var sum = tabell.reduce(add, 0);

function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

const gjenn =  (sum/tabell.length);
console.log(gjenn);
return gjenn;
}

beregn.onclick = function display() {

    console.log(beregn(Array));

}
```

using "beregn" as both a function name and an id for an object in HTML caused issues. Changed element ID in HTML and js and that fixed the issue.
Alternative code:

```
var Array = [];

leggtil.onclick = function leggtil() {

    const input = +document.getElementById('input').value;
    Array.push(input);
    console.log(Array);

}
function beregn(tabell) {

    var sum = tabell.reduce(add, 0);

    function add(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    const gjenn =  (sum/tabell.length);
    console.log(gjenn);
    return gjenn;
}

display.onclick = function display() {

    console.log(beregn(Array));

}
```